# Getting selected values in Angular

Tags: angularjs, steroids

I've got the following HTML (building hybrid app using steroids):

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Once a day</option>
    <option value="2">Once a week</option>
</select>

<li class="item item-checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="resumes">
  </label>
  Resumes
</li>
<li class="item item-checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="linkedin">
  </label>
  LinkedIn
</li>
<li class="item item-checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="mycco">
  </label>
  myCCO
</li>
```

Is there a way in Angular to get the selected value from the `select` and all of the selected checkboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure just add [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to each

```
<select ng-model="data.period">
    <option value="1">Once a day</option>
    <option value="2">Once a week</option>
</select>

<li class="item item-checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input  ng-model="data.resumes" type="checkbox" value="resumes">
  </label>
  Resumes
</li>
<li class="item item-checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input  ng-model="data.linkedin" type="checkbox" value="linkedin">
  </label>
  LinkedIn
</li>
<li class="item item-checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input ng-model="data.mycco"  type="checkbox" value="mycco">
  </label>
  myCCO
</li>
```

In your controller:

```
// Contains all your data
$scope.data = {};
```

However you might consider doing the whole form validation/submit thing such as https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation